# IPhone PhoneGap Email Composer SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am creating an application using "IPhone, Phonegap, & Email Composer" plugin from phonegap.

I want my application to send mail using "Email Composer". Everything works fine until i return back to HTML from E-mail Composer.

I am surprised, I loose my database(SQLite) connectivity. Even I tried to create new connection but it throws me "SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18" error. I got stuck in this.

After Googling:

- I shifted my connectivity code to a new external JS file and included it to HTML. &
- Reduced my database size < 5MB

But even I am unable to connect to DB.

Can any one please help me in this issue.

Comment: Answer is here, I can confirm fix works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005811/phonegap-ios-dom-exception-18

Comment: @Henry this is real issue, any one has solution, what to do, i tried your link and with cordova 1.7 still hard luck.